# Why is it the ATC recording of Ethiopian Airlines Flight 302 is not yet available online?

Tags: air-traffic-control, accidents

I understand sites like liveatc.net constantly stream the conversation between the ATC and pilots. Why is it that there's no such recording for Ethiopian Airlines Flight 302 yet?

Comment: There are privacy laws in other countries that prohibit recording third party conversations. LiveATC is not available in every country for that reason.

Comment: For audio to be available requires two things. First, an actual recording has to exist, from ATC, CVR and/or public recordings. That may not be available in every part of the world. Second, whatever authorities are in charge have to release the recordings. That involves law, politics, and all sorts of other 'messy' stuff.  I don't know about this specific flight, but you certainly can't assume that flight audio is available in all cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [LiveATC FAQ](https://www.liveatc.net/faq/):

> LiveATC provides many of the major airport feeds on the network but most of the feeds are provided by volunteers. For this reason we sometimes have only limited control over where (and when) new feeds come online.

The coverage is not global, and in some countries (e.g., UK) it is illegal to broadcast it (that's why you can't find any UK airport on that site).

Officially, CVR/ATC recordings (transcripts are a different matter) of accidents are not made public, unless there is a civil lawsuit (jurisdiction dependent). See: [Does the NTSB provide CVR audio recordings alongside transcripts in accident reports?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3454/14897)

Answer (score 1):

If the recording has not surfaced "yet", it likely won't. LiveATC recordings are hosted by volunteers and are not "official." The "official" tapes rarely are ever heard by the public.