# Are Belarusian ATC recordings available for Ryanair Flight 4978?

Tags: air-traffic-control, diversion

I am interested in locating the ATC recordings of Ryanair Flight FR4978, [LGAV to EYVI, 23/5/2021](https://www.radarbox.com/data/flights/FR4978/1585866872), that had a forced diversion to UMMS in order to arrest a passenger.

I have looked online but couldn't find any recordings available, the closest I found was https://www.liveatc.net/, but wasn't able to find the relevant files, because I don't know the ARTCCs of the controllers they were talking to.

Comment: I think you and about a couple of hundred or so media organizations are probably trying to get a transcript of this right now!

Comment: Belarussian Department of Aviation released a transcript, see the bottom of http://caa.gov.by/ru/news-ru/view/1-203/ (website is overloaded, here is a copy: https://pastebin.com/ZZXrES84). Not a recording and not an impartial source, so I'm making it a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @aland Neither of those work for me, unfortunately. It may be my location, however.

Comment: Why is the question closed? The message says it's "not about aviation", but it clearly is. Would a rollback to revision 1 help, to make it more general?

Comment: @user000001: It says "This question does not appear to be about aviation, *within the scope defined in the help center"* – if you followed the hyperlinks you'll [arrive here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This falls under "resource location", which is off-topic here as the Stack Exchange model isn't the best fit for it. Now, if you asked *why* instead of *where*, then this should help: [Why is it the ATC recording of Ethiopian Airlines Flight 302 is not yet available online?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/61189/14897)

Comment: @ymb1: That's why I mentioned revision 1, there I asked how can one locate the ATC recording, not "please locate this for me". Feel free to add an answer to the [meta question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4227/why-was-the-question-asking-how-to-locate-atc-recordings-of-a-specific-flight) about this though.

Comment: The full transcript is now available here in Russian: https://mediazona.by/chronicle/FR4978

Answer (score 18):

Not every country allows recording and publishing of ATC communication. The UK for example does not: [Is it illegal for Joe Public to listen to ATC in the UK?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/is-it-illegal-for-joe-public-to-listen-to-atc-in-the-uk)

While I don't know for sure, I'm guessing Belarus does not allow it. LiveATC has a [coverage map](https://www.liveatc.net/map/feedmap.php?v=19120301), which shows the destination airport EYVI (Vilnius) is covered, but nothing in Belarus is:

[image: LiveATC coverage map]

I therefore doubt you will be able to get the recording. Since the incident is currently being investigated by multiple countries and organizations, a recording or a transcript might be available in the future as part of the investigation report.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so the only option is to wait for whatever media is published by the authorities. I'm gussing one shouldn't hold his breath for this though, since the authorities responsible for the incident are in Belarus.

Comment: @user000001 the records will be available in the planes blackbox. It shouldn't take too long for them to be published.

Comment: @JonathanReez a standard CVR only keeps the last 2 hours. Don't know about the one in that specific aircraft, but if it's indeed 2 hours there won't be anything interesting on it. Also I'm not sure CVR data can be extracted outside of accident investigations.

Answer (score 3):

an excerpt, maybe carefully chosen, released by a Russian TV channel, dubbed in Russian though...

Comment: I cannot play videos at my location, so al I see is the sentence you wrote. Could you transcribe?

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer. The [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) advises: *"Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*