# How can I find telephone numbers for FAA ATC facilities?

Tags: air-traffic-control, faa

It is often desirable to call an FAA air traffic control (ATC) facility on the telephone:

- To ask a question about a "[mark-the-tape](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/what-happens-when-i-tell-atc-to-mark-the-tape)" incident
- To [request a tour](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/615/what-is-the-security-policy-for-getting-into-a-control-tower)
- To notify the facility of unregulated nearby operations like [RC plane flying](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7478/rc-flying-in-us-contacting-atc)

How can one find the non-emergency telephone number for an ARTCC, TRACON, or control tower (ATCT)?

Comment: in a mark-the-tape incident, they'll probably give it to you over the air.

Comment: also note that not all ATC facilities in the US are FAA, some are contract towers.

Comment: @falstro Not if you (the pilot) are the one requesting the tape be marked. And yes, information on locating contact information for contract towers would be useful too. (Hint: FSS can give you that info whether it's a contract tower or not.)

Comment: Might be, the only occasion I've witnessed (LiveATC) the tower asked if he wanted a number to call when he asked them to mark the tape. YMMV of course, but they'll probably give it to you if you ask for it, as it is usually easier to deal with it over the phone than to duke it out over the air :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would think the control tower phone numbers would be listed prominently and conveniently on the FAA website.
You would however be wrong<sup>1</sup>.

Your best bet would be to contact the [Flight Standards District Office](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo/) that covers your area - they can get you in touch with whatever other branches of the FAA you might need to talk to. You can also get tower phone numbers from Flight Service (1-800-WX-BRIEF).

[AC-U-KWIK](http://acukwik.com) also has tower phone numbers in a conveniently searchable system (punch in the airport identifier and it will be in the results you get), and the [printed edition of the AOPA airport directory](http://www.aopa.org/Products-and-Services/AOPA-Airports-Directory-Print-Edition.aspx) used to have tower numbers as an appendix (I'm pretty sure it still does).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> – Actually that's not strictly correct: [*some* regions](http://www.faa.gov/airports/runway_safety/aso/Regional_Airports/) publish tower numbers prominently. Most don't, or my search skills aren't good enough to find them.</sup>

Comment: The A/FD is available in a searchable digital format here http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/ and should contain all information found in the printed AFD.  Note that there may be delays in publishing the most recent directories.

Comment: @DavidWilkins does the A/FD have tower phone numbers? I remember looking for this info a while ago and not finding it in there...

Comment: I don't know about the Tower/TRACON, but if you look under facilities, you should be able to find an Airways/Facilities number which is always an FAA number.  From there, they should be able to direct you to the proper place.

Comment: If it's a controlled airport you can probably get it from the airport managers office as well.

Comment: +1 for AC-U-KWIK. I just looked up my facility and can confirm that the listed phone number will actually ring the phone in the tower (not the recorded line, but the phone in the back).

Answer (score 2):

Near the end of the Chart Supplement there is a list of ARTCCs and airports with 24 hour phone numbers.

The Chart Supplement also has the number for the Airport Manager for every airport. They should be able to get you in touch with the tower if it is not on the list.

You can download these pages in ForeFlight or directly from the [FAA](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/) website. 
[image]

[image: Airports]

Answer (score 0):

For the U.S.:

AIR TRAFFIC CONTROL TOWER (ATCT), 
TERMINAL RADAR APPROACH CONTROL (TRACON), 
AND AIR ROUTE TRAFFIC CONTROL CENTER (ARTCC)
TELEPHONE NUMBERS AND LOCATIONS

http://www.csobeech.com/files/ATC-Phone-Numbers.pdf

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! The document you linked to is over 10 years old: it's from 2005/2006. Do you have a current version, and preferably from an official source, i.e. the FAA themselves?

Comment: That looks like a great link, except that it is so outdated.

Answer (score 0):

The [FAA digital products page](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/search/) that JScarry linked to needs some explanation of how to find the phone numbers. It took me a while to find where the phone numbers are located. Go to the Browse Airports/NAVAIDs map, select your region or state. In the Search Results table, select a "NC" link in "Vol / Back Pages" column. The entire 171 page PDF will be downloaded. Around page 17 is the list of TRACONS, towers and ARTCCs and their phone numbers. They certainly hid the phone numbers well.

Here is another website that appears to be current, but not as detailed as the official FAA document: [123ATC.com](https://123atc.com/facilities) It seems to be geared towards a career as a controller.