# TFR based on an invisible VOR?

Tags: vor, tfr

A new TFR was recently published, which references the Riverside (RIS) VOR/DME.

When I look at the [relevant chart](https://skyvector.com/?ll=39.09823753365181,-94.63769050449685&chart=112&zoom=4&fpl=undefined) in SkyVector, I don't see such a VOR in that area.

When I put the [ID "RIS"](https://skyvector.com/?ll=51.72362551045031,-0.8084106333195411&chart=301&zoom=4&fpl=undefined) into SkyVector, it takes me to an intersection outside London, UK.

[PilotNav has the info](http://www.pilotnav.com/navaid/faa-1356), but that took a lot of searching.

How is one meant to interpret this TFR if the nav aid is so hard to find?
Why didn't they use bigger and easier NavAids like MCI or ANX, which are not far away, and clearly depicted on the charts?

---

**Update!**
After I brought this to the attention of the local offices, they canceled the TFR and issued a new one expressed in terms of the MCI VOR, which makes a lot more sense.    The FAA was incredibly responsive and helpful!

Comment: RIS was [discontinued](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/techops/navservices/transition_programs/vormon/) in September 2017. Maybe they just copy pasted an old TFR without checking.

Comment: Thanks @fooot.  Confirmed here as well: http://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/navigation/the-faa-is-shutting-down-308-vors/

Comment: This would be an good thing to [call and ask them](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/45159/62) about; Kansas City Center is the responsible ARTCC. It certainly looks like the TFR is based on a decommissioned and uncharted navaid, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I sent a note to the local FSDO via their webform.   I may try to contact them in other ways.

Comment: The secret service owes you one!

Comment: See if the Secret Service will let you take Air Force One up for a few trips in the pattern!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I brought this to the attention of the local offices, they canceled the TFR and issued a new one expressed in terms of the MCI VOR, which makes a lot more sense. The FAA was incredibly responsive and helpful!

They didn't explicitly say it was a mistake, but I think they decided it was better to use an operational VOR.

(however, a couple weeks later, they referenced the RIS VOR again in a NOTAM.)

Answer (score 0):

ForeFlight shows it on the airport at Wheeler Downtown. [image]

Comment: Garmin Pilot has it as well.  But isn't the Paper Chart the authoritative source?

Comment: Probably not anymore, actually.